BottomSheetDialogFragment in landscape can NOT dismiss when touch right outside area
I have done the following code, it only works when I touch top outside area.
When I touch right outside area, it does NOT work!
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}

The link is a simple view to show the situation.
Touch green check area can dismiss the dialog.
Touch red cross area can NOT dismiss the dialog.

post the layout of your BottomSheetDialogFragment
